# Inline conditional statement using haml css

Tags: css, haml

How do you write inline if else in haml/css?
Here is my working code:

```
- if unit > 10
  = value
- else
  .unit
    = value
```

I tried to make it inline like the below, but that doesnt work:

```
%span{class: ('my-value') if unit > 10})
```

Comment: You have a miss placed parenthesis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parenthesis are evaluated first, so you will have 'my value' set as the class when unit in greater than 10.

```
%span{class: ('my-value' if unit > 10)}
```

Comment: you might want to add an explanation for it.

Answer (score 3):

For simple cases like this I prefer the ternary operator:

```
%span{class: unit > 10 ? 'my-value' : nil}
```

If it gets any more complicated than a simple condition I would extract it to a helper:

```
%span{class: unit_class(unit)}
```

And then in your helper file:

```
def unit_class(unit)
  if unit > 10
    'my-value'
  else
    'something-else'
  end
end
```